# Prolog - How to remove N number of members from a list

Tags: list, prolog

So I'm making a predicate called removeN(List1, N, List2). It should basically function like this:

```
removeN([o, o, o, o], 3, List2).

List2 = [o].
```

The first argument is a list with a number of the same members ([o, o, o] or [x, x, x]). The second argument is the number of members you wanna remove, and the third argument is the list with the removed members.

How should I go about this, I was thinking about using length of some sort.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What should it do if the list members are different?

Comment: It should fail, but it's not very important, as the provided list will always be a list of O's.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach would be to use `append/3` and `length/2`:

```
remove_n(List, N, ShorterList) :-
    length(Prefix, N),
    append(Prefix, ShorterList, List).
```

Answer (score 3):

Think about what the predicate should describe. It's a relation between a list, a number and a list that is either equal to the first or is missing the specified number of the first elements. Let's pick a descriptive name for it, say list_n_removed/3. Since you want a number of identical elements to be removed, let's keep the head of the list for comparison reasons, so list_n_removed/3 is just the calling predicate and another predicate with and additional argument, let's call it list_n_removed_head/4,  describes the actual relation:

```
list_n_removed([X|Xs],N,R) :-
   list_n_removed_head([X|Xs],N,R,X).
```

The predicate list_n_removed_head/4 has to deal with two distinct cases: either `N=0`, then the first and the third argument are the same list or `N>0`, then the head of the first list has to be equal to the reference element (4th argument) and the relation has to hold for the tail as well:

```
list_n_removed_head(L,0,L,_X).
list_n_removed_head([X|Xs],N,R,X) :-
   N>0,
   N0 is N-1,
   list_n_removed_head(Xs,N0,R,X).
```

Now let's see how it works. Your example query yields the desired result:

```
?- list_n_removed([o,o,o,o],3,R).
R = [o] ;
false.
```

If the first three elements are not equal the predicate fails:

```
?- list_n_removed([o,b,o,o],3,R).
false.
```

If the length of the list equals `N` the result is the empty list:

```
?- list_n_removed([o,o,o],3,R).
R = [].
```

If the length of the list is smaller than `N` the predicate fails:

```
?- list_n_removed([o,o],3,R).
false.
```

If `N=0` the two lists are identical:

```
?- list_n_removed([o,o,o,o],0,R).
R = [o, o, o, o] ;
false.
```

If `N<0` the predicate fails:

```
?- list_n_removed([o,o,o,o],-1,R).
false.
```

The predicate can be used in the other direction as well:

```
?- list_n_removed(L,0,[o]).
L = [o] ;
false.

?- list_n_removed(L,3,[o]).
L = [_G275, _G275, _G275, o] ;
false.
```

However, if the second argument is variable:

```
?- list_n_removed([o,o,o,o],N,[o]).
ERROR: >/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

This can be avoided by using CLP(FD). Consider the following changes:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).              % <- new

list_n_removed([X|Xs],N,R) :-
   list_n_removed_head([X|Xs],N,R,X).

list_n_removed_head(L,0,L,_X).
list_n_removed_head([X|Xs],N,R,X) :-
   N #> 0,                                  % <- change
   N0 #= N-1,                               % <- change
   list_n_removed_head(Xs,N0,R,X).
```

Now the above query delivers the expected result:

```
?- list_n_removed([o,o,o,o],N,[o]).
N = 3 ;
false.
```

As does the most general query:

```
?- list_n_removed(L,N,R).
L = R, R = [_G653|_G654],
N = 0 ;
L = [_G653|R],
N = 1 ;
L = [_G26, _G26|R],
N = 2 ;
L = [_G26, _G26, _G26|R],
N = 3 ;
.
.
.
```

The other queries above yield the same answers with the CLP(FD) version.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution using [foldl/4](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=foldl/4):

```
remove_step(N, _Item, Idx:Tail, IdxPlusOne:Tail) :-
    Idx < N, succ(Idx, IdxPlusOne).
remove_step(N, Item, Idx:Tail, IdxPlusOne:NewTail) :-
    Idx >= N, succ(Idx, IdxPlusOne),
    Tail = [Item|NewTail].

remove_n(List1, N, List2) :-
    foldl(remove_step(N), List1, 0:List2, _:[]).
```

The idea here is to go through the list while tracking index of current element. While element index is below specified number N we essentially do nothing. After index becomes equal to N, we start building output list by appending all remaining elements from source list.

Not effective, but you still might be interested in the solution, as it demonstrates usage of a very powerful foldl predicate, which can be used to solve wide range of list processing problems.

Answer (score 1):

Counting down should work fine

```
removeN([],K,[]) :- K>=0.
removeN(X,0,X).
removeN([_|R],K,Y) :- K2 is K-1, removeN(R,K2,Y).
```

Comment: I would recommend using `succ(K2, K1)` instead of `is/2` because it succeeds in both directions. Not probably important here though.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.
I think this is the easiest way to do this.
`trim(L,N,L2)`. `L` is the list and `N` is number of elements.

```
trim(_,0,[]).
trim([H|T],N,[H|T1]):-N1 is N-1,trim(T,N1,T1).
```

Comment: You are collecting the first N elements, not removing them.