# Accumulate list recursively, gives multiple results because of bungled backtracks

Tags: prolog

```
rank(1).
rank(2).
rank(3).
rank(4).
rank(5).
rank(6).
rank(7).
rank(8).


fold_rank(Rank, [], [], _).
% https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46676080/prolog-how-to-remove-n-number-of-members-from-a-list
fold_rank(Rank, [_Rank|Rest], Files, SS) :- 
  rank(_Rank),
  length(RemoveFiles, _Rank),
  append(RemoveFiles, _Files, Files),
  fold_rank(Rank, Rest, _Files, SS).


fold_rank(Rank, [Role|Rest], [File|FRest], [Role-File|SS]) :-
  fold_rank(Rank, Rest, FRest, SS).
```

I am trying to parse one piece of a FEN string in form:

"kqpnbrqk" or it can replace how many letters it skipped in string like:
"8", or "1qpnbrqk" or "4br1k", or "kqn5". So in total counting the skipped letters there are 8 letters.

So each letter corresponds to a file a thru h, so I pair the input with the list [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h], skipping the numbers.

Here's how I use it:

```
?- fold_rank(8, [l,x,y,z], [a,b,d,c], Ls).
Ls = [l-a, x-b, y-d, z-c|_] ;
false.
```

It completely bungles on numbers, giving me multiple results, which is what I don't want.

```
?- fold_rank(8, [1,l,l,1], [a,b,d,c], Ls).
Ls = [l-b, l-d|_] ;
Ls = [l-b, l-d, 1-c|_] ;
Ls = [1-a, l-b, l-d|_] ;
Ls = [1-a, l-b, l-d, 1-c|_] ;
false.
```

I traced it but I don't understand how backtracking works, i don't see what the problem is.

Could you also explain why this gives multiple results and how I have to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

```
fold_rank(Rank, [], [], []).
% https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46676080/prolog-how-to-remove-n-number-of-members-from-a-list
fold_rank(Rank, [Char|Rest], Files, SS) :- 
  (n(Char, RRank)
  -> (
    length(RemoveFiles, RRank),
    append(RemoveFiles, FFiles, Files),
    fold_rank(Rank, Rest, FFiles, SS)
  ) ; (
  Files = [File|FRest],
  char_role(Char, Role),
  char_color(Char, Color),
  SS=[Color-Role-(File-Rank)|SSRest],
  fold_rank(Rank, Rest, FRest, SSRest)
)).
```

No thanks to you, I've solved it. Just explain how this works.